# Assign to ASP.NET identity to AD group for accessing remote SQL Server

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, iis, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 (IIS 7.5) application running on a server(Window Server 2008 R2 Standard), named WEBSERV, and a SQL Server (2008) database on another server, named DATASERV. The SQL Server has a login setup as user for my database with read privileges. I am the owner of the AD group that is associated with the SQL Server login, named READGROUP and I use to access the database using integrated security, which I understand is Windows authentication. The ASP.NET application's app pool identity is set to NetworkService. Anonymous authentication is enabled. ASP.NET impersonation, Basic authentication, Digest Authentication, Forms authentication, Windows Authentication all disabled. I can enable these if need be. For me to give a human user read access to the database, I add them to the READGROUP.

My goal is to add a 1 non human user to the READGROUP so that the ASP.NET application can may query the database and display data in the HTML table. I have the code working on my dev box, but its operating with my credentials, which has access to the data because I'm a part of READGROUP. When the app is running on WEBSERV, its Windows Identity is showing up as "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service".

I do not want to store my password on WEBSERV like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xzyzb0f.aspx). I have to change it every 90 days and this is a major pain to maintain, and the IT people strongly discourage it.

Is there any way to get a specific user for WEBSERV + ASP.NET + my application  added to my AD group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the computer account for WEBSERV as a SQL login.

You can do this from T-SQL:

```
CREATE LOGIN [WEBSERV$] FROM WINDOWS;
```

or from the GUI by creating a login as you normally, but entering `YOURDOMAIN\WEBSERV$` in the search dialog when searching for the AD account.

After this you may map the user to the database as you normally would.

It may be desirable to instead create an AD User to use as the service account for the application pool identity, give it an extremely long password, and set the flag 'Password Never Expires' on the account. This is arguably more secure that granting access to the computer account but it depends how flexible your IT department is on password policy for service accounts.

Using your own AD account as a service account is a bad idea in any case.